# A missing address in a letter causes a "There's no line here to end." error

Tags: letters, compilation-error, scrlttr2

Consider the following LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
  \opening{}
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

Why does this error happen, exactly? It goes away if I add something, anything, to the address field, i.e. the second arg of `\begin{letter}`. For example `\phantom{}` makes the error go away.

I'm looking for a detailed analysis, which I hope I will learn something from.

Comment: If the address field should be empty use option `addrfield=false`: `\begin{letter}[addrfield=false]{}`. If all letters in the document should have empty address fields, then you could use `\documentclass[addrfield=false]{scrlttr2}` or `\KOMAoptions{addrfield=false}`.

Comment: @esdd Thanks. That's very helpful. I didn't know there was such an option.

Answer (score 7):

the error comes from `\\`  if there is no text before it ("no line to end") so presumably this class is using `\\`  after  the address. `\mbox{}` probably the simplest thing that is an invisible text

To see more add

```
\errorcontextlines=100
```

then your document produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \endgroup 
\\->\ifhmode \unskip \else \@nolnerr 
                                     \fi \par \@ifstar {\nobreak \@xcentercr...
<argument> ...font {toname}{\usekomavar {toname}\\
                                                  }}{\usekomafont {toaddress...

\\@savevbox ...4#5#6->\begingroup \vbox to #2{#1#3
                                                  }\if@savevbox@warning \@sa...

\rlap  #1->\hb@xt@ \z@ {#1
                          \hss }
<argument> ...MessageBreak \string \specialmail }}
                                                  }
\vb@t@z ...x \z@ \vbox to\z@ {\color@begingroup #1
                                                  \color@endgroup \vss }\set...

\@addrfield ...sageBreak \string \specialmail }}}}
                                                  \vskip -\useplength {toadd...

\opening ...arks \@firstheadfootfield \@addrfield 
                                                  \@locfield \ifdim \useplen...
l.5   \opening{}
                
?
```

Within the error stack you see the call

```
\usekomavar {toname}\\
```

which is adding `\\`  after `toname` which will fail if that is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error message are explained in the other answers, so my answer is a bit off topic.

To avoid the error message you have to use option `addressfield=false`. For a single letter this option can be set for the `letter` environment itself

```
\begin{letter}[addrfield=false]{}
```

or using`\KOMAoptions` or `\KOMAOption` before `\opening`:

```
\begin{letter}{}
\KOMAoptions{addrfield=false}% or \KOMAoption{addrfield}{false}
\opening{}
```

If all letters in the document should have empty address fields, then you can set `addrfield=false` while loading the class

```
\documentclass[addrfield=false]{scrlttr2}
```

or using `\KOMAoptions` or `\KOMAOption` in the preamble.

You could also patch the `letter` environment to set `addrfield=false` automatically if the argument is  empty (ie. no space etc.):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\letter}{\IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{\KOMAoptions{addrfield=false}}{}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
%\setkomavar{toname}{Bar}
%\setkomavar{toaddress}{Bar Address}
  \opening{}
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\begin{letter}{Foo\\Foo Address}
  \opening{}
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

But then there will be no address field even if the variables `toname` and `toaddress` are not empty. Note that these variables can be set in the preamble, outside the `letter` environment or between `\begin{letter}{}` and `\opening`.

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful information.